# SQL window functions - how to associate the latest login time for each row data?

Tags: sql, window-functions

Suppose we have a table EVENTS in RDBMS with three columns: userid, event, timestamp, where each row records the timestamp for an event by a user. Let's say the possible events include: login, view, checkout, bookmark, cancel_order, etc.

How can we associate the login timestamp for each row? The login timestamp is the latest login event that is before the event of interest, of a specific user.

(I was thinking about the window functions, but could not come up with a proper solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative conditional max:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when event = 'login' then timestamp end) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as latest_login
from t;
```